# Inviting people with Trello API

Tags: php, api, curl, trello

i'm trying to invite a person via email to Trello from my website. Here is the [API reference](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/organization#put-1-organizations-idorg-or-name-members). When I try to invite him, the plain reply is "invalid key". Here is my function:

```
public function inviteEmployeeToTrello ($email, $name, $isAdmin)
{
    $organazationTrelloID = 'myOrganazationID';
    $trelloAuthToken = 'myTrelloAuthToken';
    $trelloInviteUrl = 'https://trello.com/1/organizations/'.$organazationTrelloID.'/members';

    if ($isAdmin == 1)
    {
        $type = 'admin';
    }
    else
    {
        $type = 'normal';
    }

    $fields = array(
        'fullName' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'type' => $type,
        'token' => $trelloAuthToken
    );

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set the url, number of PUT vars, PUT data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trelloInviteUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // exec
    $replyRaw = curl_exec($ch);
    $reply = json_decode($replyRaw, true);

    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    dd($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS does not want a JSON, 
if you want a urlencoded request, use http_build_query($fields) , or if you want a multipart/form-data request, just give it $fields array directly. (the API doc's doesn't seem to mention which request types it accept, though. urlencoded is the most common one.)

Comment: thanks! I've added my key to the $field array and replaced the json_encode($fields) with http_build_query($fields) and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

As the error code says, you forgot to pass your [application key](https://trello.com/app-key). Here's an example from the [API reference](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/organization#put-1-organizations-idorg-or-name-members) :

> https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/publicorg?members=all&member_fields=username,fullName&fields=name,desc&**key=[application_key]**&token=[optional_auth_token]

You have to include it in your query, hence in your case, add it to the 
`$fields` array :

```
$fields = array(
    'fullName' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'type' => $type,,
    'key' => $trelloAppKey
    'token' => $trelloAuthToken
);
```

Comment: thanks! I've added my key to the $field array and replaced the json_encode($fields) with http_build_query($fields) and now it works!